# Как корректно вывести ссылку с экранированием кавычек?

Tags: php, html, ссылки

Есть ссылка, которая включает в себя функции, переменные и др. параметры с кавычками. Как корректно вывести строку, чтобы она корректно отображалсь на выходе? Проблема со ссылкой

```
echo "<a href='".bloginfo('url')."/ad-category/".mb_strtolower($category->name). "/' rel='tag' class='cp-fixed-color'>". $category->name. "</a>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)

```
$url = bloginfo('url')."/ad-category/".mb_strtolower($category->name). "/";
echo urlencode($url);
```

судя по всему `bloginfo('url')` у вас возвращает имя домена сайта, то есть `site.ru`. Тут во-первых ссылки надо указывать относительные (если они на свой же сайт), а во вторых экранировать имя домена, конечно не надо в таком случае.

Если ссылка на страницы вашего же сайта, то ссылка должна выглядеть как-то так

```
   $url = "/ad-category/".urlencode(mb_strtolower($category->name)). "/";
```

Если внешний, то `$url = bloginfo('url').$url;`

В общем говоря, с помощью `urlencode` кодируется не весь адрес, а передаваемые параметры, или те части адреса, который могут содерржать неоднозначности.

Comment: а в каком виде? вот так не работает...
`echo "<a href='".urlencode(bloginfo('url'))."/ad-category/".mb_strtolower($category->name). "/' rel='tag' class='cp-fixed-color'>". $category->name. "</a>";`

Comment: @Вася пардоньте, пропустил. что у вас с ссылку еще и название категории вписывается.

Comment: получаю примерно так `http://site%2Fad-category%2F%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%2F`

Comment: @Вася еще раз обновил ответ